# feature.GetAttributeValue to get value of attribute value from feature table

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I am trying to get the attribute value related to a selected feature on Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.ArcGISFeature.

I am able to zoom and pan to the object.

But when I use this code:

```
Field plotno_1 = Testfeature.FeatureTable.GetField("plotno_1");
string strPlot = Testfeature.GetAttributeValue(plotno_1).ToString();
```

I get this error only on the second line of code.

Even if I use the overload for GetAttributeValue("plotno_1"), I get the same error.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

---

I have noticed that the data returned is null and maybe that is why the GetAttributeValue function returns an error.

---

Problem identified

I discovered that the plotno_1 field is not present in the returned query.

Is it possible to query for only a single field or it possible for someone to show me, with code, how to retrieve all fields from a **SelectFeature** query?

Here is the code snippet that I am using.

```
// Create globally available feature table for easy referencing
private ServiceFeatureTable _featureTable;

// Create globally available feature layer for easy referencing
private FeatureLayer _featureLayer;


var Testtable = _featureTable;

//var Testtemplate = Testtable.FeatureTemplates.FirstOrDefault() ?? Testtable.FeatureTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Templates.Any()).Templates.FirstOrDefault();
var Testfeature = Testtable.CreateFeature();
Testfeature.Geometry = e.Location;

if (Testfeature != null)
{
    EnvelopeBuilder envBuilder = new EnvelopeBuilder(_featureLayer.SpatialReference);

    // Add the extent of each matching feature to the envelope.
    envBuilder.UnionOf(Testfeature.Geometry.Extent);

    // Select each feature.
    _featureLayer.SelectFeature(Testfeature);
    
    

    // Zoom to the extent of the selected feature(s).
    await MyMapView.SetViewpointGeometryAsync(envBuilder.ToGeometry(), 9);

}
```

I can actually iterate through all the fields but when I try to use the **GetAttributeValue** using the same loop that shows the fields I get the error indicating that the field is not present and in some cases null

Comment: it's possible. If the value is null, you end up with `null.ToString()`, which would throw that exception

Answer (score 0):

Use your debugger to step through and inspect what is null. Any operation you perform on that like `.ToString()` will cause that error to happen.
I would also encourage you to ensure you have null annotations turned on if you're targeting .NET6+ (add `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` to a property group in your csproj), and the compile would warn you exactly where you're not guarding against potential null values.
So first check that `plotno_1` isn't returning null. Next check that the value you're getting from the attribute isn't returning null before calling ToString on it (or use the Elvis operator `?.ToString()`).

If the attribute is missing, and you're using a ServiceFeatureTable, it could be because it's by default not loading all attributes (for performance reasons it only loads just enough to render it). However you can ensure all attributes are fully loaded by calling this before accessing the attributes:

```
if(Testfeature is ILoadable loadable)
   await loadable.LoadAsync();
```

There are also ways to set the layer to load more attributes, or query with full set of attributes, but for performance reasons I'd generally recommend not doing that unless you expect to be looking at ALL the features (like in a datagrid), and instead pull data on-demand like this when you need it.